# MySQL Stored Procedure: Can I update directly with the cursor?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

It's probably a really easy question, but I couldn't find an answer to it myself:

When I have a cursor pointing to the row I want to update, is there a faster way than to issue an UPDATE statement?

```
DECLARE current_id, current_product_id, current_price, current_position INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE new_position INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cursor_offers CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id, product_id, price, position FROM offers 
    ORDER BY product_id, price ASC;

OPEN cursor_offers;
offers_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_offers INTO current_id, current_product_id, current_price, current_position;
    # Loop control omitted
    # Conditional statements omitted, that calculate new_position

    UPDATE offers SET position = new_position WHERE id = current_id; # <--- This line
END LOOP offers_loop;
```

I figure that as MySQL already has a pointer to that line via the cursor, it would be inefficient to find it again in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: As far as I know the cursor is for the result set, not the table itself. Also there is a lot more to UPDATE-ing a row than just knowing where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html). It says that cursors are read-only and can not be used to update.

So I'd say it's not possible to directly update using a cursor. You'll have to issue an update statement.